# Determine number of points within geographic subdivisions?

Tags: d3.js

I have a map of Russia, showing its subdivisions.

I have points plotted on that map. How do I determine how many points are located within the boundaries of each subdivision?

Comment: You could run points and subdivisions through `d3.geoContains()` [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#geoContains). While D3 can do this, depending on the volume of points and your use case, it may be wiser to calculate this once (either with D3 or GIS software) to create a new dataset which is used to render your visualization.

Comment: I'm trying to use that, but I'm getting: `Uncaught TypeError: d3.geoContains is not a function`

Comment: Got it working! It's only available in d3 v4+, and I was using v3. Thanks!